# Get access token automaticly

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
        FB.init({
          appId      : '1565121060381861',
          status     : true,
          xfbml      : true
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        var fbd = function(){
            FB.api('/220753401365634/feed?access_token=', function(response){
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    console.log(response);
                }else{
                    console.log('error');
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        }
```

I'm trying to get feed, from my fb page. I get access token, from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

and it works. but if I log out from my fb, on the web page I have error:

```
code: 190
error_subcode: 467
message: "Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out."
type: "OAuthException"
```

How can I get access token in correct way?

Comment: That is the right way. If you log out the access token will not be valid anymore

Comment: why are you even dealing with the access token and not just using FB.login? you really need to check out the facebook docs.

Comment: luschn 
because I don't need to login.

I fixed it. thank you anyway